# How can I hover my ::after element in styled component

Tags: css, pseudo-element, gatsby, styled-components

I try to hover my `::after` element using styled components but it doesn't work.

Below I paste my code which I expect should work well but it doesn't.

```
const Div = styled.div`
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
postition:relative;
&::after{
  content: '';
  background:rgba(255, 193, 5, 1);
  position:absolute;
  top:60%;
  left:-15%;
  width:20vw;
  height:20vw;
  border-radius:50%;
  &:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
`
```

Comment: You can't hover a pseudo element. You could only apply the styles when the parent is hovered. `div:hover::after { }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `:hover` on an `::after` pseudo-element. You can read more about this in [this blog by Martin Wolf](https://martinwolf.org/before-2018/blog/2015/05/why-you-can-do-hoverafter-and-not-afterhover/).

The code you have supplied isn't the best to work with as there's not much context on what your project is, but it should look something like so in Sass (which I assume you are using?).

```css
.example-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    postition:relative;

    &::after{
        content: '';
        background:rgba(255, 193, 5, 1);
        position:absolute;
        top:60%;
        left:-15%;
        width:20vw;
        height:20vw;
        border-radius:50%;
    }

    &:hover {
        &::after {
            transform: scale(1.2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I Read  Exactly what I needed in article. I'm not usings Sass by the way